# Exporting and Importing data from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, transfer

I made an application that stores data to SQLite database. What I wanna do now is to send (via Bluetooth or Share-It or any other alternatives) the data from one device to another device so that the data will be used by the same application from another device. I have searched many times but I always get irrelevant results. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is probably not the best solution. However, you could do this with SQLite two ways.

### 1. Transfer the entire Database

One way would be to copy the entire database from the source and then overwrite the file at the destination. This method has the drawback that there is little, if any, protection of the data (e.g. say user 2 has an empty database and sends it to user 1 who loads it, all data lost).

### 2. Select and Send the Appropriate Data

The other way would be to extract the data via a query, format it it appropriately (make is CSV or perhaps JSON etc), send it, and then use an update/insert query to load the new data. Obviously this would entail having a methodology to prevent duplication/ outdated updates.

Alternative solutions would be to have a centralised database, Firebase being Google's offering.

Comment: maybe ill just use 2nd solution but through online transaction. thanks :)